# Binding from multi object in to one value in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a ListView which have a DataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FilterDataTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ComboBox x:Name="TermsItemComboBox" Width="160"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" Tag="{Binding}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectionChanged="AddTermsItem_SelectionChanged"
        Background="#FFD1D1D1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="TermsInputTxt1" Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay}"
        BorderBrush="#FF727272" Background="#FFD1D1D1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Width="200" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Visibility="{Binding IsTxtForm, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Height="45"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="TermsInputTxt2" Text="{Binding FilterText, Mode=TwoWay}"
        BorderBrush="#FF727272" Background="#FFD1D1D1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Width="200" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Visibility="{Binding IsTxtForm, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
        Height="45"/>

    <Button x:Name="TrashBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderBrush="#FF575757" Foreground="#FF494949" BorderThickness="2" Tapped="TrashBtn_Tapped"
        Style="{StaticResource DiscardAppBarButtonStyle}" Height="45" Width="55"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

It's have a combobox and two TextBox. At default, the combobox don's show anything, just a blank item, I want when user type some text to the TermsInputTxt1 or TermsInputTxt2, the combobox will select the first item.

I try to bind the selectedindex of combobox with the lenght of those two textbox with a converter but look like XAML doesn't support multi binding like that.

Any suggest? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a bit of a difficult situation. You have a couple of ways of going about it:

- Bind the `TermsInputTxt1` and `TermsInputTxt2` to the `ViewModel`, with the Setter on the `ViewModel` controlling an `ObservableCollection`, adding and removing items as they get set in the property.
- Create a `Model` for each entry with a Value field (`string`) and bind the `Terms...` to accessors in the `ViewModel`. Then, the `ComboBox` items will automatically change.

I suggest doing the first one. You'll have to have a `SelectedItem/SelectedIndex` property in the `ViewModel` which the `ComboBox` will bind to. You may also want to change the method by which the binding on the `TextBox`s are updated, either so that they are updated immediately (lots of processing) or after it loses focus (less processing, but won't update the UI immediately).

Comment: Can we access to the TermsInputTxt1, TermsInputTxt2 and combobox from code behind? If yes, I think it'll easier for this situation.

Comment: You can, but it is difficult. You'll have to parse the `VisualTree`. Look up [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com), as it has some helpful extensions for that, such as `GetDescendends<Type>()`.

Comment: Thank for your suggest, I try to do the first solution which you suggest, but I cannot make the textbox binding when user typing, it's only work when lost focus on the textbox, I'm developing with the WIndows 8 environment, I don't see the UpdateSourceTrigger or something like that, any idea?

Comment: UpdateSourceTrigger was added in Windows 8.1. There are ways to do it with Behaviors and some extensions though. I think WinRTXamlToolkit has something for that in it as well.